# WPF autocompletebox populating programmatically

Tags: c#, wpf, autocompletebox

My autocompletebox works/populates perfectly if you use a physical keyboard to start typing. I am trying to change the autocompletebox programmatically and have the populating drop down display as if I'm using a physical keyboard. Right now the value changes but its like the populating event isn't being triggered.

autocompletebox

```
<toolkit:AutoCompleteBox x:Name="eventSearchBox" Populating="eventSearchBoxPopulating" FilterMode="Contains"/>
```

this code changes the value but doesnt fire the populating event.

```
eventSearchBox.Text = "something";
```

Comment: Can you fire the event manually after changing the text?

Comment: Couldn't find a way to do that

Answer (score 1):

```
eventSearchBox.IsDropDownOpen = true;
```